# Can't change wallpaper from CLI in Ubuntu (works fine from GUI)

Tags: ubuntu, dconf, gsettings

Please help me to find out the list of command required to process a operation in GUI ?

For example,

If I change the wallpaper from GUI what is the command behind this .

Actually I was trying to change the background using the below command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file://(Path of the image)
```

But it resulting in below error:

```
(process:2658): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed
```

But when I tried deleting old `~/.config/dconf` but the error still there.

From GUI I can easily change it.

Comment: You forgot to use "sudo".

Comment: @Rinzwind - really ? I can't believe Ubuntu is so dumb that it requires `sudo` to change a _user setting_...

Comment: Why? A user does this from a gui (there is a system in place there to allow this). Doing it from command line should need elevation.

Comment: @Rinzwind - it doesn't on any of the (sane) distros I'm using. I can't see _why I'd need sudo to change any of my files_. I mean really...

Answer (score 2):

Changing background depends on desktop environments, I use Mate and I change background picture using the following command:

```
gsettings set org.mate.background picture-filename /path/to/file.jpg
```

I'm not sure about other desktop environments but you should check if your desktop exists using tab completion

```
gsettings set org.* [2tabs]
```

and again not sure what do you want to know from command functionalities but I usually use "strace" to track down all works behind the scene after command execution.